# Unit testing in the WordPress backend (is_admin() is true)

Tags: wp-admin, testing, unit-tests

I've asked this on IRC, Twitter, Slack — am utterly astonished by how difficult it is to locate the answer to this:

I have a bunch of plugin code that only runs when `is_admin()` returns `true`, i.e., when the user is looking at the admin panel.

How do I arrange a unit test such that it's in the admin context when the assertions are run?

Comment: try define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );

Comment: @Scriptonomy *frowns* That's changing the underlying config of WordPress. Is this really how people are told to do it?

Answer (score 12):

According to [this test](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/tests/phpunit/tests/rest-api.php#L267), you use `set_current_screen()` to navigate to [one of these](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference) in the `setUp` method.

Alas, none of this is apparent if you look at the tremendously-helpful reference page for [get_current_screen()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_current_screen)...

Example:

```
<?php
class AxisSetupTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {    
    /**
     * @covers AxisWP::__construct
     */
    function test_constructor() {
        // Assert

        // Admin
        $this->assertInternalType('integer', has_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( 'AxisWP', 'add_admin_stylesheet' ) ) );
    }


    public function setUp() {
            parent::setUp();

            $user_id = $this->factory->user->create( array( 'role' => 'administrator' ) );
            $user = wp_set_current_user( $user_id );

            // This is the key here.
            set_current_screen( 'edit-post' );
    }

    public function tearDown() {
            parent::tearDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that I eventually had to essentially instantiate the class and then call the methods manually *anyway* as the load order was funky and causing weird failures. The tl;dr is — don't bother testing any part of WordPress itself, instantiate your class manually and run your functions and assert output based upon that.

Comment: Yes, I do essentially the same thing as this when the code being tested uses `is_admin()` or `is_network_admin()`. However, you might want to `unset( $GLOBALS['current_screen'] )` in your `tearDown()` method (otherwise you could just remove it since it isn't needed if all it does is just call the parent method :-).